# Default xml namespace but not on root using XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

So what I am doing is using XmlSerializer and using a custom class. One of the elements requires a default namespace and its own value also. The default namespace though is required to be dynamic. So Athens is the namespace for that locations element. Next location element could be London. For example:

```
<items>
    <item>
         <location xmlns="Athens">True</location>
         <location xmlns="London">False</location>
    </item>
<items>
```

I have tried using XmlSerializerNamespaces but that wont allow me to use an empty string for the first parameter. And all the examples I have seen are for the root element. I am looking to have it work for the following class setup.

```
[XmlRoot("item")]
public class Item
{
     [XmlElement("location")]
     public string Location { get;set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can embed an `XElement`-valued property inside your class that is populated on demand with the necessary namespace and value, then decorate it with the [`XmlAnyElementAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlanyelementattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute to tell `XmlSerializer` to include it as-is in the final XML:

```
[XmlRoot("item" /*, Namespace = "" */)] // Applies when an Item is the document root.
[XmlType("item" /*, Namespace = "" */)] // Applies when an Item is not the document root.
public class Item
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Location { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string LocationNamespace { get; set; }

    [XmlAnyElement]
    public XElement LocationElement
    {
        get
        {
            var ns = (XNamespace)LocationNamespace;
            var element = new XElement(ns + "location", Location);
            return element;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                LocationNamespace = Location = null;
            }
            else
            {
                LocationNamespace = value.Name.Namespace.NamespaceName;
                Location = value.Value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When placed (e.g.) in an array, the following classes:

```
var items = new List<Item> { new Item { Location = true.ToString(), LocationNamespace = "Athens" } };
```

would be serialized to the following XML:

> ```
> <ArrayOfItem xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
>     <item>
>         <location xmlns="Athens">True</location>
>     </item>
> </ArrayOfItem>
> ```

**Update**

Your updated question needs an array of locations in each `Item`.  You can do that by having your `XmlAnyElement` return an array of `XElements`:

```
public class Item
{
    public Item()
    {
        this.Locations = new List<string>();
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public List<string> Locations { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Location { get; set; }

    [XmlAnyElement]
    public XElement [] LocationElements {
        get
        {
            var elements = Locations.Select(l => new XElement(XName.Get("location", l), (l == Location).ToString())).ToArray();
            return elements;
        }
        set
        {
            Locations = value.Select(el => el.Name.Namespace.NamespaceName).ToList();
            Location = value.Where(el => bool.Parse(el.Value)).Select(el => el.Name.Namespace.NamespaceName).Distinct().SingleOrDefault() ?? string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Then the following

```
        var cities = new List<string> { "Athens", "London", "Salt Lake City" };
        var items = new List<Item> { new Item { Locations = cities, Location = cities[0] }, new Item { Locations = cities, Location = cities[1] } };
```

Produces the following XML:

> ```
> <ArrayOfItem xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
>     <item>
>         <location xmlns="Athens">True</location>
>         <location xmlns="London">False</location>
>         <location xmlns="Salt Lake City">False</location>
>     </item>
>     <item>
>         <location xmlns="Athens">False</location>
>         <location xmlns="London">True</location>
>         <location xmlns="Salt Lake City">False</location>
>     </item>
> </ArrayOfItem>
> ```

Comment: Very sorry forgot to mention the namespace would not be a constant. I iterate through a list of locations and each one has to be set dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

you can specify a namespace for the element as well, try this

`[XmlRoot("item")]
public class Item
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "location", Namespace="Athens")]
     public string Location { get;set; }
}`

Comment: Very sorry forgot to mention the namespace would not be a constant. I iterate through a list of locations and each one has to be set dynamically.